# Netezza LIKE operator not finding subsequent backslashes

Tags: character-set, netezza, like

Netezza is able to find records when using the LIKE operator when the first character contains a backslash character.  But when subsequent characters contain a backslash character, it cannot.  How can I correct this?

**Result set has records:**

SELECT *
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE PATH LIKE '\some_path%'

**Result set has 0 records:**

SELECT *
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE PATH LIKE '\some_path\%'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to avoid the escape character in the pattern matching string (after the LIKE), and append `ESCAPE ''` to avoid using the backslash as an escape character.  In this example, I had `_` characters in the literals, as well as `\` characters.